# How to search on Google using Python and Google API?

Tags: python, ajax, google-search, google-search-api

I've searched the whole afternoon but I'm still stuck.

I need to google keywords, and save the ranks of a given domain name for each keyword.

I tried to use several libraries : xgoogle, google, and pygoogle. However, pygoogle just doesn't work, and google, pygoogle always end up raising "HTTP Error : Service Unavailable".

So I suppose I should use the Google API, that uses the libraries urllib2 and simplejson, as well as the URL "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0".

I have several questions :

- How to choose the top level domain ?
- How to choose the langage of the results ?
- How to choose how many results are shown ?
- Are the results ranked the way I should find them in my own Google search ? I'm asking the question since I'm under the impression it's not the case.
- Are the photos URL taken into account ?
- How to choose the starting URL ? Is it possible to start from the 10th result ?

Thank you for your help,
Sebi81

Comment: Could you post your code that doesn't work please?

Comment: Can you get it to work with a simple curl call against the Google API? Then you would know for sure whether problem is in how you are using their API, or in how your program is communicating.

Comment: Actually I managed to solve the question of the language and the starting URL, which were my major problems.

But I just realized that the results from the google API are not the same than those from my own google requests...

I searched a bit and found that this issue has existed since 2008 and is still unrepaired. Maybe I should try something different from the google API then...

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling : here is the code that doesn't work :

domainName = 'wikipedia'

maxResult = 10

rankings = {}

for keyword in keywords : 
    k = 0
    rank = 0
    alreadyFound = False 
    for url in search(keyword, num=1, start=0, stop=maxResult, lang = langCode):
        k = k+1     
        if (not alreadyFound) and (str(domainName) in str(url)) : 
            rank = k
            alreadyFound = True
    if rank != 0 : 
        rankings[keyword] = rank
    else : 
        rankings[keyword] = 'more than ' + str(maxResult)

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling : 
it uses the google library
In the beginning it works just fine but after a few requests it stops working since Google blocks me

I should connect to a proxy but I can't manage to allow it by modifying the google library.
Here is another question of mine about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242000/how-to-add-proxy-connection-to-python-library-google